# Правильно ли построено следующее предложение?

Tags: грамматика

Грамотно ли следующее предложение?

«Сотрудника уволили и завели на него уголовное дело».

Мне почему-то оно кажется странным. Вот если бы было что-то вроде «сотрудника уволили и арестовали», то и вопросов бы не было.

Из-за порядка слов возникает ощущение, что главное слово здесь «сотрудника», от него и зависят сказуемые. Но по сути зависит от него только сказуемое «уволили», а вот «завели» относится уже к другому дополнению, потому и выглядит все как-то неграмотно. Может я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение построено *безупречно* и отвечает на вопрос: что сделали с сотрудником (неопределённые лица, неназванным образом разделившие между собой два действия)? Местоимение с предлогом "на него" однозначно указывает на "сотрудника" и относит к нему заведение уголовного дела. Эта однозначность сохраняется и при разделении предложения на два неопределённо-личных:

> Сотрудника уволили. На него завели уголовное дело.